# Overriding a method that has an Exception Compiler Error

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-errors, polymorphism, subtype

The code below 'a.eat()' causes a compilation error that needs to be either declared or caught.

```
class Animal {
   public void eat() throws Exception {}
}

class Dog extends Animal {
 public void eat() {}

 public static void main(String [] args) {
   Animal a = new Dog();
   Dog d = new Dog();
   d.eat(); 
   a.eat();//Causes compilation error as 'a' was not declared or caught
   }
}
```

Why is it the case that the compiler still thinks you are calling a method that declares an exception? Why doesn't the compiler see that the method has been overridden by the sub type as in 'd.eat()'?

Comment: Because `a` is an `Animal`.

Comment: Because in general, it can't see that.  And it has to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler only knows that `a` is an `Animal`.  That is because it's perfectly legal to have

```
class HairballException extends Exception {}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public void eat() throws HairballException {}
}
```

and then before `a.eat();`:

```
a = new Cat();
```

The variable `a` can be *any* class that is an `Animal`.  The compiler cannot assume that `a` is still a `Dog`, so it must enforce that it can throw `Exception`.

If you really don't want to catch the `Exception` that `Animal`'s `eat()` method may throw, then cast `a` to a `Dog` before calling `eat()`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the actual object referred to 'a' is of type Dog, the class of the variable 'a' is class Animal.

Therefore at compile time the compiler assumes a.eat() might throw an exception because Animal eat() method declares it and thus expects this call to be either wrapped in a try catch or for the the method caller to have a throw clause.